# Spotify /authorize endpoint

Tags: python, web-applications, spotify, webapi, spotify-app

I would like to know which is the /authorize endpoint, after some search I see that it's https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_ID, but why? where is the documentation about it? I don't see any endpoints list and the guide only tell me to "send a GET request to the /authorize endpoint" without tell me which is the endpoint.
Sorry, I only want to know the logic behind the endpoint address

Thank you

Comment: You can read everything about the Authorization Code Flow [on this page](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/).

Comment: You can get access token by express with client id/secret. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466868/errorinvalid-client-client-credentials-error-spotify-with-express/74493282#74493282